# How to check if date in Table 1 fits between 2 dates in Table 2, and merge tables if ID value also matches?

Tags: mysql, dataframe, time-series, forecasting

I have two SQL tables.

```
Table1
ItemNum,Date,Sales qty 
 
Table2 
ItemNum,StartDate,EndDate, promotionValue.
```

I want to check if the Date in table 1 falls under Start and End dates in table 2, and if the ItemNums also match, I want to add the promotionValue column to the Table 1 relevant row.

How can I do this in mySQL?

Comment: Have you tried `select  t1.ItemNum,t1.Date,t1.Sales,t1.qty,t2.promotionValue from Table1 t1  inner join Table2 t2 on t1.ItemNum=t2.ItemNum and t1.Date between  t2.StartDate and t2.EndDate ` ?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ItemNum = t2
WHERE t1.Date >= t2.StartDate AND t1.Date <= t2.EndDate;
```